# PageMethod and Intellisense

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, pagemethods

i am working with VS2010 but

function GetSessionVal() 
{
           PageMethods.GetViewState(onSuccess)
}

when i write PageMethods and dot then server side method name in my case "GetViewState" is not showing in auto completion list. do i need to set anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(By Auto-complete word in your question, I think you mean Intellisense)

Did you read somewhere that PageMethods will appear in Intellisense? I am not sure of heard or read this before. I tried to search but could not get anything specific with 
this. So if that's not supported in general, then it may not appear. If you get some reference post it here.

On a side note, a general solution for Ajax intellisense is that you can delete the cached schema for ajax which is available at following path (on windows 7, for xp similar path). Git it a try.

C:\Users\***username***\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ReflectedSchemas

Answer (score 0):

Type in protected override and you might get intellisense on Page Methods available to override.